# "install" command as script

Tags: linux, coreutils

I'm working on a heavily modified Linux based OS targeted for a really specific environment - easy-to-use NAS systems. It does not provide any GUI, apart from a web interface, but it at least has SSH.

I'm trying to run a manual package build (as far as "./configure && make" is manual), but it fails at one specific point - it cannot find the install command. As the platform misses a multitude of otherwise essential and default Linux commands, I'm not surprised by this, but by the fact that a good half-hour search resulted in no hits about how to replace it. Seriously, nobody ever thought about having a simple bash script that has the same functionality?

So question is - how to replace "install"? Is there any script or executable that does the exact same, on x86/bromolow platform  (or platform-independently)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`automake` ships with a shell-script variant for this exact case.  You'll usually find it in `/usr/share/automake-<ver>/install-sh` (where `<ver>` is to be replaced by the version, e.g. `1.11` or `1.14`):

```
$ file /usr/share/automake-1.14/install-sh
/usr/share/automake-1.14/install-sh: POSIX shell script, ASCII text executable
$ /usr/share/automake-1.14/install-sh --help
Usage: /usr/share/automake-1.14/install-sh [OPTION]... [-T] SRCFILE DSTFILE
   or: /usr/share/automake-1.14/install-sh [OPTION]... SRCFILES... DIRECTORY
   or: /usr/share/automake-1.14/install-sh [OPTION]... -t DIRECTORY SRCFILES...
   or: /usr/share/automake-1.14/install-sh [OPTION]... -d DIRECTORIES...

In the 1st form, copy SRCFILE to DSTFILE.
In the 2nd and 3rd, copy all SRCFILES to DIRECTORY.
In the 4th, create DIRECTORIES.

Options:
     --help     display this help and exit.
     --version  display version info and exit.

  -c            (ignored)
  -C            install only if different (preserve the last data modification time)
  -d            create directories instead of installing files.
  -g GROUP      chgrp installed files to GROUP.
  -m MODE       chmod installed files to MODE.
  -o USER       chown installed files to USER.
  -s            strip installed files.
  -t DIRECTORY  install into DIRECTORY.
  -T            report an error if DSTFILE is a directory.

Environment variables override the default commands:
  CHGRPPROG CHMODPROG CHOWNPROG CMPPROG CPPROG MKDIRPROG MVPROG
  RMPROG STRIPPROG

$
```